# How to do a mysqldump with a use database in the dump

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

So the command I normally use to get a database sent to another server is:
mysqldump -u *user* -p --add-drop-tables *database* *file*

But I always have to go into the *file* and add a line at the top:
use *database*;

So that I use the file to import to a different server. Is there a flag in mysqldump to automatically add the use *database*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The flag is **--databases**

```
mysqldump -u user -p --add-drop-tables --databases database > *file*
```

So if you have more than one schema names you need to set which databases with the **--databases** flag. Then it inserts which one is necessary to be used.

Comment: There is no `--add-drop-tables` flag, it should be `--add-drop-table`.

Answer (score 6):

We do use key `-B <db-name>`, which adds command `USE <db-name>;`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding: --databases THE_DB_NAME

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can write a small bash script or batch file (depending on OS) with the lines you want to add to the file.